# Generic entity for raw queries in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF and I have to execute some custom queries that user can create as they need.

I know that for a raw queries I have to use `SqlQuery`, but I do not know the object that the query returns.

I am using a `UnitOfWork` pattern:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class
{
    CellularFiveLocalEntities context = null;
    public Repository()
    {
        context = new CellularFiveLocalEntities();
    }

    private DbSet<TEntity> EntitySet
    {
        get { return context.Set<TEntity>(); }
    }

    public List<string> RawQuery(string query)
    {
        List<string> result = null;

        try {
            var entity = context.Set<string>();
            result = entity.SqlQuery(query).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            throw ex;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use a generic object for custom queries?

Comment: Why don't you know the object that is being queried? I assume you're not just outright allowing users to query your database at will through the repository.

Comment: The user know the database and he can create new queries in the app, i hope you understand

Comment: If your users know the schema, then why don't they use a query tool to query it? You can't just query through entity framework without giving it a mapping of some form. It is after all an ORM

Comment: you mean that i can not execute queries through EF? SO i have to use ADO for queries that i do not know the object?

Comment: There are ways (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-SqlQuery) but I would recommend asking yourself why you are providing an end user with the ability to query the database directly

Comment: Well, they do not query the database directly, they can create custom queries and save it into a table in database so they can execute it when they need it, Like example, they saved a query like: Select, User1, User2, Adress From Table1, Table1 Where user like '%John%'